# React - Checking for a value in an uncontrolled input?

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hook-form, use-ref

I've got a custom Input control, which I'd like **to be uncontrolled**. I don't care what the user writes or where this is stored. However, **I need to know if the input has some value or not**, because depending on that it will have an appearance or another (such as a floating label).

Since **it's not possible to check purely by CSS** if an input has a value or not (because the attribute `value` does not get updated when the user types and changes its value), the only way to know if it has a value or not is programatically.

If I use `useState` to keep a local state of its `value` just to know if it has some (though it keeps being uncontrolled), whenever **some external script changes the value of the input using `ref`** (for example, `react-hook-forms` `reset` function), it **won't get updated** because the state won't notice the change, and thus the input will be empty but its state will think it still has a value.

As it's not a possibility, then, I wanted to access and *watch* for the `ref` `.value` changes. However, it doesn't change (or, at least, it doesn't notify the change). If I access the `value` prop directly, it has the correct value, but it doesn't trigger the `useEffect` although what I'm using as a dependency is the `value` and not the `ref` itself.

```
  const [hasValue, setHasValue] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHasValue(!!inputRef?.current?.value);
  }, [inputRef?.current?.value]);
```

[Here is Codesandbox a sample of what I'm referring.](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-water-oc6tc1?file=/src/Input.jsx)

Is there any way to check the actual value of the input inside my custom component **without having to send a `value` prop from the parent**, which is able to react to external changes by
`ref`, too? So, **no matter how the input value changes**, it's aware of it.

Comment: add an id on `<input id='inputTag' />` and use `document.querySelector("#inputTag").value`

Comment: The same happens. It only reacts for the first change, and only in one of the inputs if you render multiple of them. It's like when the input changes its inner value it alerts no one.

Comment: Faced the same issue just now. Any workable solution so far?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't find any solution to this, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Inder's suggestion with vanilla javascript or you could trigger your useEffect with afterValue, which gets set onChange.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const Input = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [afterValue, setAfterValue] = useState("");
  const [hasValue, setHasValue] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHasValue(!!inputRef?.current?.value);
  }, [afterValue]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
          setTimeout(() => setAfterValue(value), 1000)
        }
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div>Has value: {hasValue.toString()}</div>
      <div>Actual value: {inputRef?.current?.value}</div>
      <div>After value: {afterValue}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Comment: The thing with this is that, as I commented, any value changes done by external libraries using `ref` won't trigger this, and the state will be incorrect because the value will be another (even empty) and the local state will think it still has a value. I cannot use anything related with the `onChange`, because any change caused by a non-keyboard event won't be captured.

Answer (score 0):

I'he got a very similar issue with this library. And there are two possible solutions for that.

1. Solution with local state in custom component

   ```
        export const FormInput = forwardRef((props: FormInputProps, ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement>): JSX.Element => {
          const {onChange, label, explanation, optional, errorMessage, ...rest } = props;
          const [localValue, setLocalvalue] = useState('');

        return (
          <div className={inputWrapperClasses}>
          <input
            className={inputClasses}
            ref={ref}
            {...rest}
            value={localValue}
            onChange={e => {
                onChange && onChange(e);
                setLocalvalue(e.target.value)
            }}
        />
   ```

You need to define onChange handler that way, that it updates your local state, as well as library state with its onChange(e).
Then even on reset() call, onChange will be triggered, and will update both states with empty value, and your label will be properly styled

2. Solution with passing value property from parent.

Yes, it is what you didn't want to do, but since it works, it what I stick with, and it can be a solution for someone else in the future, I decided to share.
Pass value property as a result of calling watch function from useForm hook, and then in your custom component pass it to native input as value={value} or data-value={value}.

```
                        <FormInput
                          value={watch('phone')}
                          {...register('phone', { pattern: { value: phonePattern, message: 'Please, enter a valid phone' } })}
```